# IIS ASP.net Get the windows username of the user accessing the site without them logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a website that is hosted on an IIS web server. Within this site, I would like to access the username of the person logged on to the computer that is being used to access the site. However, I don't want them to have to log in. I have enabled windows authentication and identity impersonate in the web.config file. I have also enabled windows authentication and disabled anonymous login within IIS manager. I am receiving a login prompt from the browser and when i enter my credentials, they do not work.

I would like to know how to get rid of the login prompt and allow anyone to access the site while still being able to retrieve their windows username

Answer (score 0):

According to your descritpion, the only way to achieve your requirement is modify IE setting to access your web application.

The IE has the security setting which will send the current login in windows user name and password automatically.

More details about how to modify the IE setting, you could refer to below article.

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication

[image]